# How to use custom video control components like play, pause, mute etc on shaka player?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video, media-player, shaka

I am using the latest version(3.2.0) of shaka player on my react project.

I am currently trying to hide the UI controls on shaka player and trying to use custom components like trickplay, play, pause, CC selector, Audio language selector, volume bar, seek bar and running time.

I have made shaka player video object available on the windows object and trying to hook the UI controls with the custom components that I have created.

```
const video = document.getElementById('sampleShakaPlayer');
const shakaInstance = new shaka.Player(video);
```

To pause the playback, I am trying the function below

```
shakaInstance.pause();
```

But this doesn't seems to work. How can I achieve this?

The shaka documentation is super vague and I am unable to find the appropriate functions to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `video.play()`, they are the same methods are HTML5 video tag.

Also take a look at https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/1238

Answer (score 0):

Use configure method of shaka player. with that you can manipulate the controls like hide show. In controlPanelElements whatever the controls you pass it will show that only. Example-  controlPanelElements: ["rewind", "fast_forward" 'play_pause', 'mute','time_and_duration', 'spacer', ''fullscreen', 'overflow_menu'],

```
const video = document.getElementbyid('video');
    const ui = video['ui'];
    const config = {
      addSeekBar: false,
       controlPanelElements: ['play_pause'],
        seekBarColors: {
        base: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)",
        buffered: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
        played: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        },
    };
    ui.configure(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for custom `rewind/fast-forward` and `volume controls`, take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/shaka-player-ui-controls